# What is SpinedBuffer in java and how does it work?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In Java Stream API implementation they use a data structure which they call `SpinedBuffer`, in java Doc they describe it as below:

> One or more arrays are used to store elements. The use of a multiple arrays has better performance characteristics than a single array used by   {@link ArrayList}, as when the capacity of the list needs
> to be increased  no copying of elements is required.  This is
> usually beneficial in the case where the results will be traversed
> a small number of times

I want to know :

1. How this data structure use multiple array to improve performance
2. There is another concept which is called chunk in the implementation of this data structure, what is chunk and how do they use it to implement this data structure

Comment: `ArrayList` allocates a single array.  If you keep adding elements to it, at some point the array is too small.  You'll need to reallocate the array, and copy everything in it so far to the new one.  This `SpinedBuffer` instead has a list of chunks.  When you keep adding elements to it and all the chunks are full it just allocates a new chunk (with an array inside it) where it can add more elements.  The existing chunks donot need to be copied when this happens.

Comment: [`SpinedBuffer`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/SpinedBuffer.java)

Comment: You can look at the source code. Java is open source.